# Terminology: the effect when fitting with two correlated independent variables

Tags: regression, terminology

When fitting with two correlated independent variables without regularisation, you can get two coefficients offsetting each other, eg one large positive and the other large negative. Is there a specific name for this effect?

Comment: It is not always the case that both coefficients will be large or even of opposite signs, so are you asking about the near *lack of identifiability*, about the *multicollinearity*, or about this specific behavior of large opposite signs in the coefficient estimates?

Comment: @whuber, I modified the question to make it clear. I think multicollinearity is the cause of the effect -- is there a word for the effect itself?